# Javascript: modifying a paragraph inside a <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create in javascript a code that modifies text and images inside a  in html. The aim of this code is to hide an show a text by clicking buttons, all of this inside of a  tag

This is the html code i am using (index.html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/js.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

            <button id="hide">Hide</button>
            <button id="show">Show</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the javascript file (js.js):

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#container #hide").click(function () {
        alert("hide pressed");
        $("#container p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function () {
        alert("show pressed");
        $("p").show();
    });
});
```

I have searched the web, and many tutorials put this structure as a working structure, in my case is not working. As u can see the show and hide code in the javascript structure are different, these are the two configurations i have found to test the code, and both of them fail.

I have compiled this exercice with "brackets" and tested it in internet explorer, mozilla firefox and google chrome.  The code is not woking on any of them, any solution to make this working?

PS: If I remove the "use strict" command, "brackets" complain of the lack of it.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/61ctq7bm/. Based on your HTML I assume you haven't included jQuery. Are you aware that you are using jQuery? It's a library that you have to include. Check out its tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery in not included by default in the browser**. You need to add it by putting this `<script>` tag in your head. This will include the JavaScript file where jQuery is coded.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Also, only one element can have an ID, so `$('#container #hide')` can be just `$('#hide')`

Comment: The link you give me it's correct, but the second part is false. The double ID is the path to the element, it work both ways as i put in the question.